# Determining the correct Android WebView screen size after soft keyboard hides with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android

**I'm working on a "Mobile Web" app, and relying completely on javascript to solve this problem**. On certain Android devices, most notably the Samsung Galaxy family, a **window.resize** event fires when the soft keyboard appears, shortening the height of my **screen.height**. When a user taps the "Go" button of the soft keyboard, my app reloads with a height that is less the height of the soft keyboard.

Now, I am listening to the **window.resize** event, so if the user rotates the device, everything will right itself. However, ***I'm hoping to figure out a way to fire off the window.resize event programmatically***, so that every action performed when I rotate the device is triggered.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery mobile use jQuery [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

if not use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript/2505969#2505969) code from a stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript):

> You can use fireEvent on IE, and w3c's dispatchEvent on most other
>   browsers. To create the event you want to fire, you can use either
>   createEvent or createEventObject depending on the browser.
>
> Here is a self-explanatory piece of code (from prototype) that fires
>   an event dataavailable on an element:

```
    var event;
  if (document.createEvent) {
    event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent("dataavailable", true, true);
  } else {
    event = document.createEventObject();
    event.eventType = "ondataavailable";
  }

  event.eventName = eventName;
  event.memo = memo || { };

  if (document.createEvent) {
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  } else {
    element.fireEvent(event.eventType, event);
  }
```

Update:

There is a `fireEvent()` for IE and `dispatchEvent()` method for non IE browser. You can manually fire your events. The trick is to create an event just like `window.resize` and fire that. I never tried this. But I hope that can help.

Comment: Mohsen, I tried this but it didn't solve the issue. If I could fire the same event that's fired by the browser with this technique, that would help, but I don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: Are you using jQuery there? if yes, you just need to write $(window).trigger('close');

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and abandoned trying to fire the events and went with modifying the meta viewport after keyboard has gone. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321889/1500269